# What is the time complexity of this combination generator

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I want to generate all combinations of k numbers from a set of n numbers as long as k is less than or equal to Ceiling(n / c) where c is a constant. What will be the time complexity of such an algorithm in big O notation? Will complexity be exponential, polynomial, pseudo-polynomial, other?

E.g:
n = 10, c = 3
All combinations of 1 out of 10 plus all combinations 2 out of 10 plus 3 out of 10 and plus 4 out of 10, because Ceiling(10/3) = 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are an exponential number of things to return, and therefore it has to be exponential.

To prove that, it suffices to prove that `n choose floor(n/c)` grows exponentially fast for any given `c`.  To prove that you just have to prove that `log(n choose floor(n/c))` is `O(n)`.  And to prove that you can use the well-known formula for choose and [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).